# Simultaneous Loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I'm trying to loop through two variables at the same time. Normally I would: `for j, k in zip(vara, varb)`

however, `vara` is actually a nested array (I hope I'm using that term correctly. As in `vara` looks like `[[0,25], [25,50], [50,75],etc]`

I was hoping this would work, but it didn't: for `(j,k),l in zip((vara), varb)`

Any suggestions?

`vara = [[0,25], [25,50], [50,75], etc]`

`varb = [24,53,75,13,etc]`

And I am hoping to output

```
 [0,25] & 24
 [25,50] & 53
  etc.
```

Comment: What error did you get? That type of tuple unpacking should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't (work)"? Follow your for loop up with a print statement and you shoud get exactly what you expected.

Comment: This worked for me. Can you provide us with the errors?

Comment: Ah i was trying to call `l` with `varb[l]` instead of just `l`... silly me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's working even on python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating as you have done works fine (in Python 3.4). You use tuple-unpacking to unpack the returned values from `zip` and then further tuple-unpacking to get the individual elements of each `vara` element.

```
vara = [[0,25], [25,50], [50,75]]
varb = range(len(vara))

for (j, k), l in zip(vara, varb):
    print(j, k, l)
    # 0 25 0
    # 25 50 1
    # 50 75 2
```

Alternatively you could assign the nested element to a list and then use indexing as needed:

```
for j, l in zip(vara, varb):
    print(j[0], j[1], l)
```

Comment: Ah i was trying to call `l` with `varb[l]` instead of just `l`... silly me. Thanks for the help!